# GNUplot: string value in ternary operator

Tags: gnuplot

Coming back to an old project and have obviously forgotten something here.
Datafile:

```
2017-03-31 14:38   6.42 feet  High Tide
2017-03-31 20:40   -0.30 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-01 02:56   6.92 feet  High Tide
2017-04-01 06:34   Full Moon
2017-04-01 09:19  -0.58 feet  Low Tide
2017-04-01 15:33   6.17 feet  High Tide
```

When I plot as follows, all works fine except the ternary operator to test for the string(s) in strcol(3):

```
set terminal aqua size 950,594
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
unset key
set samples 1000
set xtics 86400
set x2tics 86400
set xtics nomirror font "Gill Sans Light,14" tc rgb "blue"
set grid ytics back
set grid x2tics
set format x "%a" 
set format x2 "%d" 
set xdata time
set x2data time
set yrange [-1:7.5]
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "red"
myDate(col1,col2)=sprintf("%s %s",strcol(1),strcol(2))
myLabel(col3,col2) = sprintf("%s ft.\n%s",strcol(col3),strcol(col2))
plot "tidefiles-test2.txt" \
u (myDate(1,2)):3:((strcol(5) eq "High") ? (myLabel(3,2)) :1/0) with labels font "Gill Sans Light,12" offset 0,-2  tc rgb "blue",\
"" u (myDate(1,2)):3:((strcol(5) eq "Low") ? (myLabel(3,2)) :1/0) with labels font "Gill Sans Light,12" offset 0,+2  tc rgb "red",\
"" u (myDate(1,2)):3:(strcol(3) eq "Full") ?  ("●"):1/0 w labels left font "Symbola,48" offset -4,0,\
"" u (myDate(1,2)):3 lc rgb "green" lw 1  sm cspl notitle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with the string `Full` doesn't have a y-value. So, when the condition `strcol(3) eq "Full"` is fulfilled, at the same time the actual y-value is not a valid number and so that point is also skipped.

Using e.g.

```
plot "tidefiles-test2.txt" \
    "" u (myDate(1,2)):(strcol(3) eq "Full" ? 0 : $3):((strcol(3) eq "Full") ? ("●"):1/0) w labels left font "Symbola,24" offset -4,0
```

works fine, but requires you to use a hard-coded y-value. Otherwise you must add an appropriate y-value in your data file for the "Full"-case.

[image]